# CSS selector to match single list elements in a nested list

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have nested list, similar to the one below:

```
<ol>
    <li>Item 1
        <ol>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3
                <ol>
                    <li>Item 4
                        <ol>
                            <li>Item 5</li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                    <li>Item 6
                        <ol>
                            <li>Item 7</li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Items 1, 5 and 7 are all lone `<li>` elements, i.e. they are the only ones in their level of the hierarchy for that specific parent. I would like to match them and exchange them for bullet elements. (I would also be open to a JavaScript solution, though I would prefer pure CSS, if possible.)

Comment: You mean, items 2, 5 and 7... right? (1 has a nested list)

Comment: No, I do mean items 1, 5 and 7. Item 2 and item 3 are on the same level with the same parent. Item 1 doesn't have another item on that level, even though it still has a nested list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the `:only-child` pseudo-class.

See reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#only-child-pseudo

The trick requires two CSS rules.

The `ol li:only-child` rule may cause issues due to inheritance.

Use `li:only-child *` to cancel any effect from the first rule.

Seems to work okay in this example.

```css
ol li:only-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
li:only-child * {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>Item 1
        <ol>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3
                <ol>
                    <li>Item 4
                        <ol>
                            <li>Item 5</li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                    <li>Item 6
                        <ol>
                            <li>Item 7</li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Depending on the layout the OP may want to scope down the selectors to `ol > li:only-child` and `li:only-child > ol` so as not to block inheritance.

Comment: @BoltClock I like your suggestion, makes for a cleaner set of rules.  Please feel free to edit/improve the answer if you have time to add a few words.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jquery based selector, if that's any use:

```
$('li').filter(function() { return $(this).siblings().length == 0 })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ge811g5/